# asp.net Core/ - Having trouble casting a linq query to a Dto

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the following Linq statement that is currently not working.

```
var result = ClientDATARepository.AllIncluding(c => c.Jobs, c => c.ClientNotes, c => c.Suburb).Where(x => x.Id == id).Select(fetchedClient =>
                new ClientDetailsDto {
                    Id = fetchedClient.Id,
                    ClientNo = fetchedClient.ClientNo,
                    Company = fetchedClient.Company,
                    IsWarrantyCompany = fetchedClient.IsWarrantyCompany,
                    CompanyName = fetchedClient.CompanyName,
                    ClientFirstName = fetchedClient.ClientFirstName,
                    ClientLastName = fetchedClient.ClientLastName,
                    MobilePhone = fetchedClient.MobilePhone,
                    DeActivated = fetchedClient.DateDeActivated.HasValue ? "true" : "false",
                    CreatedOn = EF.Property<DateTime>(fetchedClient, "CreatedOn").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
                    ModifiedOn = EF.Property<DateTime>(fetchedClient, "ModifiedOn").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),

                    ClientNotes = fetchedClient.ClientNotes.Select(fetchedClientNote =>
                        new ClientNoteDto {
                            id = fetchedClientNote.Id,
                            Details = fetchedClientNote.Details,

                        }) as IQueryable<ClientNoteDto>
```

The initial method `ClientDATARepository.AllIncluding` is from the repository and is suppose to return the full details of a client:

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = _context.Set<T>();
            return includeProperties.Aggregate(query, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));
        }
```

Which should include all associated entities requested... which works to obtain a client however no ClientNotes are returned yet there are clientNotes in the database for the selected client.

[image]

The Dto I am trying to fill in is a follows:

public class ClientDetailsDto
    {

```
    public ClientDetailsDto()
    {
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ClientNo { get; set; }
    public bool Company { get; set; }
    public bool IsWarrantyCompany { set; get; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string ClientFirstName { get; set; }
    public string ClientLastName { get; set; }
    public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
    public string DeActivated { get; set; }
    public string CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public int SuburbId { get; set; }
    public AddressDto Address { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<ClientJobDto> ClientJobs { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<ClientNoteDto> ClientNotes { get; set; }
}
```

ClientNoteDto is also presented for completeness:

```
public class ClientNoteDto
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public string NoteType { get; set; }
    public string CreatedOnDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedOnTime { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedOnDate { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedOnTime { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

How do I get the IQueryable statement to return all the notes for this client as part of the result?

Comment: where are these DTOs going to be used ? I suspect they are IQueryable and wont return any results unless you to do smoething like ToList on it. Atleast on debugger window. If you notice ClientJobs is also null and I believe it is becasue of it !

Comment: Its an OData implementation. I didnt want to muddy the waters with that. Essentially OData, as I understand, will convert it back in the controller. It does mention that when you display results this effectively shows the results as it would if you add .ToList().

Comment: With regard to clientJobs.. I was doing the same thing as clientNotes so I commented that out so as to focus on just one part of this.. thats why its null..